# SQL Select and update users multiple users same time

Tags: sql

I have a SQL table which will hold an Id.

I need to retrieve the ID then add 1 and update the table.

The problem is users retrieving and updating at the same time.

I would like if a user is retrieving the id then I need all the other users to wait until the user gets the id and then updates.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[CPS_ID](
[ID] [numeric](18, 0) NOT NULL
```

What's the best way to do this.

```
SELECT [ID] FROM [dbo].[CPS_ID]

UPDATE [dbo].[CPS_ID]
SET [ID] = ID + 1
```

Comment: [Locking will be your friend](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/sql-server-transaction-locking-and-row-versioning-guide)

Comment: It's not a good idea to handle ID incrementing on your own.  You should use an identity type column and let the database handle incrementing an ID.  This will ensure you don't have overlaps / duplicates caused by concurrency

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/386424). What is your end goal? Why are you trying to do this?

Comment: This is normally handled using `SEQUENCE`, `IDENTITY` or `AUTOINCREMENT` columns *(specifically which depends on the exact database you're using; MySQL, Oracle, SQL Server, etc)*.  That is; when you insert a row, the databases automatically creates a new unique value in the `id` column for you, and then you never change that value.  *(Search online for concepts such as `surrogate key`)*.

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language used by all relational databases, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)